# Turning a R date value from a character class into a date class

Tags: r, class, date

My problem is that I am importing a CSV file, and trying to get R to recognize the date column as dates and format them as such.

So far I have achieved to replace the format seen below  "#yyyy-mm-dd#" with the integer date value in R.

But when I check the class before and after the transformation it still says "character".

I need the column to be recognized as a date class so that I can use it for forecasting. But

```
DemandCSV <- read_csv("C:/Users/pth/Desktop/Care/Demand.csv")
nrow <- nrow(DemandCSV)
for(i in 1:nrow){
  DemandCSV[i,1] <-as.Date(ymd(substr(DemandCSV[i,1], 2, 11)))
}
DemandCSV[,1] <- format(DemandCSV[,1], "%Y-%m-%d")
```

[image] 
[image]

Figured out an inelegant solution (turns out it was not a solution)

```
DemandCSV <- read_csv("C:/Users/pth/Desktop/Care/Demand.csv")
nrow <- nrow(DemandCSV)
for(i in 1:nrow){
  DemandCSV[i,1] <-as.Date(ymd(substr(DemandCSV[i,1], 2, 11)))
  DemandCSV[i,1] <- format(as.Date(as.numeric(DemandCSV[i,1],origin = "01-01-1970")), "%Y-%m-%d")}
DemandCSV %>% pad %>% fill_by_value(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does including the "#" in the format string solve your problem?

```
data <- c("#2019-09-23#", "#2019-09-24#", "#2019-09-25#")
a <- as.Date(data,format="#%Y-%m-%d#")
```

or

```
DemandCSV <- data.frame(date=
 c("#2019-09-23#", "#2019-09-24#", "#2019-09-25#"))
mutate_at(DemandCSV,"date",as.Date,format="#%Y-%m-%d#")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simpler to

1. Substitute out the `#`
2. Rely on `anydate` from the `anytime` package

Demo:

```
R> data <- c("#2019-09-23#", "#2019-09-24#", "#2019-09-25#")
R> anytime::anydate(gsub("#", "", data))
[1] "2019-09-23" "2019-09-24" "2019-09-25"
R>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. When I try 
`DemandCSV[,1] <- anydate(gsub("#", "", DemandCSV[,1]))`
It replaces all of my dates with NA

Comment: The something else goes on with your data. We can't tell. You posted an _image_ (== not helpful) rather than code.  See my example -- it works.